# Asp Net Core 2.2 on random address goes to controller instead of 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

If the address is well formatted everything is fine.
But when I type  random string into the address bar, asp net core routes to the same controller and in particular to Index(model)

```
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult Index() { ... }

   [HttpGet({model})]
   public IActionResult Index(ViewModel model) { ... }
```

instead of returning 404 Not found.
Is the problem with the controller?

Comment: Where in the address bar are you typing this random string?

Comment: on address bar of web browser. e.g.: http://localhost:43336/Home/somethingrandom or http://localhost:43336/ajhgkagkajhdfgkajshdgfaiurebcq

Comment: And the target controller is not HomeController

Comment: Do you have a `redirect` for errors or as a default? This could be an accident of having a custom 404 page.

Comment: `[HttpGet({model})]` is wrong, change it to `[HttpGet]`. Model can't be part of the url as it is a complex type. When normal routing can't handle the request it falls back to this method, but it can't serialize model.

Comment: What is your current `Startup.cs`? I fail to reproduce your issue with your action. Share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HomeController` is mapped to "" or the empty route, and then this second `Index` action requires basically any route portion. So, `/foobar` literally routes to this `Index` action.

There's a number of problems/misunderstandings here. When you specify `{model}` in the route, you're telling the framework that this is a route param. There's effectively no way to actually ever bind your model, because you can't actually post a representation of `ViewModel` within a route path.

Second, there is no validation of route params *during* routing. In other words, ASP.NET Core doesn't look at you action, see that it needs to be an instance of `ViewModel`, realize that `foobar` in `/foobar` is not a `ViewModel` and then returns 404. It merely sees that there's a potential route that takes *something* in that route segment, and then attempts to load up the corresponding action. It's on the modelbinding phase where things will fail, but that's after the routing is already done.

You can use route constraints to add a layer of validation. For example, `{foo:int}` would only match if the value in that route segment was something that could be cast to an int, but you can't really do that for something like `ViewModel`.

Third, you shouldn't be sending an entire model via a GET. GET doesn't have a body, and complex objects should go in the body of the request. You should be using POST here instead.

Long and short, change your action to:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(ViewModel model) { ... }
```

And you'll be fine.

Comment: As for the third point, it's perfectly alright to use HttpGet to 'post' certain html forms. There is no technical restriction: `<form method="get">`. E.g. I use it for readonly overviews where the search/paging criteria are part of the querystring. Post using F5 would need confirmation to resend the data, while Get simply reexecutes the call. It's more important to use Post when you want to send sensitive data that should be encrypted, which is only possible as part of the body. If no sensitive data is involved then `[HttpPost]` / `[HttpGet]` may be omitted as well.

Comment: That's not true. First, POST is no more secure than GET. The query string and even the route is encrypted via HTTPS. Second, I'm not talking about sending data in general; I'm talking about complex objects, such as a view model.

Comment: Yes you are right about encryption, but for other reasons GET shouldn't be used for sensitive data. As for models, for binding the source is not relevant, e.g. [FromQuery],  [FromForm], as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?#sources).

Comment: There's a difference between can and should. You can shoot yourself in the foot with a .44 magnum. I wouldn't recommend it though. Complex objects should not be sent via GET.

Comment: Your comparison doesn't hold. The discussion is about the left foot or the right foot. Why should complex objects not be sent via GET? I see no arguments or sources that support your statement.

Comment: 1) It's had practice, in general. GETs should be idempotent, and generally speaking, when you're send a full object, it's not. 2) there's a very real issue of hitting the request size limit, just because field names are verbose for model-binding purposes. 3) It's just ugly 4) You're exposing a lot of information viewable by the user. Sure, they can dig into the source if they care to, but no reason to make it easy. 5) Why deal with 1-4 when you have a request body to work with POST. It's doing something not advised just for the sake of doing it.

Comment: For restful clients POST is good practice, but in this case the client doesn't send objects. It sends key value pairs, it has no knowledge of objects. The server can 'reconstruct' objects because of (naming) conventions, where it doesn't matter in what way the key value pairs are received. What matters is whether the information should be part of the querystring or not. In case of a search form yes, because you want to allow users to save the link, like Google build it. In other situations e.g. when it contains sensitive data, not. So it depends on the situation which method is more suitable.

Comment: We're talking in circles. Something like a search is usually just going to be a single param with some keywords. An advanced search situation may be an exception to the don't send complex objects via GET, but there's ways around that even. The plain and simple point is that complex objects should be sent via POST, unless there's a very clear and rationale reason not to. Here, there isn't, so the argument is pedantic.

Comment: Agreed, everything has been said, no need to continue. And agreed that most times it's more suitable to post forms. I just wanted to point out that there are exceptions where it's valid to GET a form. And given the context, though there isn't much, since it's the `index` method this could indicate it's a search form.